# Accessing an HTTPS web service from Glassfish based web-ap

Tags: java, web-services, https, glassfish, certificate

I'm trying to access an `HTTPS` based web service URL from a web/ear application deployed
on a `Glassfish` application server domain.
We have obtained the certificate from the vendor that exposes the `HTTPS` URL.
What are the steps required for installing `SSL` certificates in order to access the web service ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the steps required for installing SSL certificates in order to access the web service ?

If the certificate is a self-signed certificate or hasn't be signed by a CA for which the JVM already has a root CA like  Thawte, Verisign, etc,  **you'll have to add it to a client trust store** and to configure the web service client or GlassFish (which is a client here) to use this trust store to establish a chain of trust.

To import the stand-alone certificate into a trust store, use `keytool`. [**This post**](http://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/java-secure-http-keys/) explains how to use it (see the section *Creating Java Key and Trust Stores*).

Then, configure the web service client to use this trust store. To do so, you'll need to define the system properties `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and maybe `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`. You can maybe do it at the GlassFish level (see this [**this post**](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kumarjayanti/archive/2009/08/26/configuring-non-jks-keystore-glassfish-v3)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure Glassfish for https?

https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/security/faq.html#configssl

or you need to install a client certificate in your browser?

Comment: My Glassfish itself need not serve any HTTPS based pages or authenticate any incoming request.
All it has is an application(EAR|WAR) that would access an external HTTPS based web service. 
Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Ah, not clear from the description.  If you run under Java 6 then the easiest is to use IntelliJ to create sources for invoking the client (using annotations).  Then you can "just" invoke that from your java code running in the WAR.

Comment: Well I wasn't running Java 6/IntelliJ
However the link you posted as very informative.